# Radio button value getting null in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a requirement of deleting a student object from list of objects. So that I have retrieved all the student objects from the DB and stored in a variable.

There is an option to filter the students, provided a textbox so that user can enter student name and the list will be filtered upon the name entered as below screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

So the user can select the particular student to delete from the filtered list using the radio button and can delete the particular student.
But the issue is currently I am not getting the radio button value in my controller.

HTML page is as below:

```
<h2 align="center">Delete Student</h2>
<div ng-controller="deleteStudentController">
<form ng-submit="submitForm()">
    Student Name:<input type="text" letters-only ng-model="searchName"/><br>
    <div ng-repeat="student in students | filter:searchName" ng-show="searchName.length">
        <input type="radio" ng-model="studentRadio" value="{{student._id}}" ng-value="{{student._id}}"/>{{student | formatter}}
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete Student"/>
</form>
</div>
```

In the controller I have alert the value of the radio button, but its not getting any value:

```
mainApp.controller("deleteStudentController", function($scope,$http) {
var resData = {};
$scope.student = {};
var urlGet = "/students/all";
$http.get(urlGet)
.then(function(response) {
    $scope.students = angular.fromJson(response.data);
});

$scope.submitForm = function (){
       alert("$scope.studentRadio"+$scope.studentRadio);
   };
});
```

My sample JSON format is
{"_id":"5765671b37f3dc940d66fad1","name":"hgh","id":"hgh","address":"hjg"}

Please help on this issue!!!!!

Comment: submitForm doesn't take argument in your definition. Your value is in  $scope.studentRadio

Comment: @Silvinus Sorry for that mistake. Actually I tried the same but not getting the output. I have tried some other solutions to fix that up. Tried to pass the value from UI to the function as aguement. and forgot to clean it up. Both are not working:(

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution. 
As this is a iterating radio button, need to give the model name as "$parent.studentRadio".

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.studentRadio" name="studentRadio" value="{{student._id}}"/>
```

Thanks all....

Comment: ng-repeat creates a separate child scope that's why $parent. worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the arg passed to submitForm.

```
$scope.submitForm = function (){
       alert("$scope.studentRadio" + $scope.studentRadio);
   };
});
```

Did you check if this works?

Comment: Sorry for that mistake. Actually I tried the same but not getting the output. I have tried some other solutions to fix that up. Tried to pass the value from UI to the function as aguement. and forgot to clean it up. Both are not working:(

Comment: Could you add a name to your radio buttons and try? Meanwhile I will check it in a jsfiddle..

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
   
    $scope.submitForm = function (){
           alert($scope.studentRadio);
       };
    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.28"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form ng-submit="submitForm()">
        Student Name:<input type="text" letters-only ng-model="searchName"/><br>
        <div>
          <input type="radio" value="1" ng-model="studentRadio" name="studentRadio">1
          <input type="radio" value="2" ng-model="studentRadio" name="studentRadio">2
          <input type="radio" value="3" ng-model="studentRadio" name="studentRadio">3
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Delete Student" />
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Try with adding Name for your radio button.

Comment: Thanks @Saurabh Sarathe. I tried the above code sniplet. Just made a modification on that:
<input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.studentRadio" name="studentRadio" value="{{student._id}}"/>

Need to give ng-model="$parent.studentRadio".
Thanks....